# Service called several times ending itself

Tags: android, android-intent, service

I am starting a service with a click on a button :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), UploadService.class);                     
getActivity().startService(intent);
```

My apps makes it possible to launch several services.
I know that the first time, onCreate() is called, then if the services is running, onStartCommand() is called.

onStartCommand returns `START_STICKY`.

But I'm facing a strange behavior : 
On the first click, the Service is called, onCreate() then onStartCommand()... etc.
On the second click, while the Service is still running, onStartCommand()... etc.

But when the first is finished, onDestroy() is called, while the second is still in progress... ?

How to avoid that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you start the Service that is already running then `onDestroy()` of Service won't be called and the instance of Service already running will be brought to front but if your Service is finished/stopped explicitly then only its `onDestroy()` will be called.

Comment: But I never call onDestroy(). I don't know why the Service destroys itself.

Comment: Hmmm... I did a mistake. Indeed I call stopService()... Now if I never call stopService(), what about them?

Comment: Your Service will keep running until the OS need some resources to kill your Service and run some other high priority task but OS will start your Service again whenever resources are available again as you are using `START_STICKY`.

Comment: Is it bad to proceed like this?

Comment: No, if you want to keeping your Service running in background you have to return `START_STICKY` else let the Service do the work and finish/stop it as soon as work is completed.